# nginx setup does not work

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I created a new instance on digital ocean and installed laravel (via cloning a git repo I have worked on). I then configured the default config for nginx, but the site is not even remotely accessible.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/mfserver/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name IPADDRESS;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The answer in the brwoser is: "SERVERIP is currently unable to handle this request."

The error I get is this in the error.log

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/mfserver/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /var/www/mfserver/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17" while reading
>   response header from upstream,$

Comment: Do `tail - n 100 /var/log/nginx/error.log` and give us that information. It should tell you what's wrong. The most common reason I see nginx fail with Laravel is because it's not owned by `www-data`.

Comment: thats strange.. I just added the error message..... what does bootstrap have to do with it?

Comment: `/bootstrap/` is the directory for core Laravel scripts that handle the response. I'm going to attempt an answer because I'm very sure what I said was true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error might have appeared if you haven't downloaded dependencies of Laravel.

Try:

```
composer install
```

or

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is unable to open Laravel core files. This is usually because of ownership problems.

Issue this command:
`ls -l /var/www/mfserver`

Chances are you'll see a list like this.

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root   4096 Apr 27 03:58 bootstrap
```

That's not right. It needs to be owned by the nginx user, typically `www-data`.

Issue this command to fix it:
`chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/mfserver`

Comment: yes.. that's what I saw. I changed this to what you suggested, but the browser does not respond in any way

Comment: Has the nginx error log changed at all, or do you get the same message?

Comment: 2016/05/04 17:43:48 [error] 3016#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /var/www/mfserver/bootstrap/app.php on line 14" while reading response header from upstream, client: 217.89.172.212, server: 139.59.142.244, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "139.59.142.244"

Comment: Need the whole line. That's a different error, which means you solved one problem and now it's encountering something else.

Comment: Oh, that's a missing vendor file. You need to run `composer update` on the `/mfserver/` directory. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation

Comment: The strange thing is that i got it runnning on a different server. But after setting up the new one it failed

Comment: Yes.. I tried this:
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /var/www/mfserver/bootstrap/app.php on line 14